# Resize Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать, чтобы поле textarea растягивалось во всех браузерах так же как в Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз надо javascript решение, то [jQuery UI Resizable Textarea](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#textarea).

Answer (score 0):

Вообще это зависит от браузера. Но как вариант можно сделать так:

```
textarea {
 resize:both;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Надо решение на JavaScript !